# How to randomize mapped elements' backgrounds?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to randomise the background color of each element

But when I insert this into the following the background color just becomes transparent:

```
{
  modules.map((module, index) => (
    <div className='carousel-module shadow'
      style={{ background: "#" + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)}}
    >
      <p className='module-element-text'>{module.name ? module.name : "N/A"}</p>
      <p className='module-element-text'>{module.code ? module.code : "N/A"}</p>
      <Button onClick={() => setShow(false)}
          variant="success" className='modules-list-button'>
          Load
      </Button>
    </div>
  ))
}
```

It would be great to hear your suggestions on how to get this working

Comment: so now it isnt working?

Comment: @Apostolos the background color just becomes transparent

Comment: What does the rendered markup look like? Your script generates 5-digit strings in some cases. Obviously that's a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function I use to generate hex color. Your method may intoduce Alpha in the color thus gets transparent

```
function randomHexColor() {
    let toHex = function (n) {
        let hex = n.toString(16);
        while (hex.length < 2) { hex = '0' + hex; }
        return hex;
    };
    let rr = toHex(Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
    let gg = toHex(Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
    let bb = toHex(Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
    return '#' + rr + gg + bb;
}
```

Comment: cool, thankyou for your effort. But how would i call this within a jsx element?

Comment: try something like this :  <h2 style={{background: randomHexColor()}}>